# How much time will Fugaku supercomputer take to generate a wordlist?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, wordlist

How much time will the Fugaku supercomputer take to generate a wordlist?

Length: 50

Combination: Alphabet(upper/lower) + numbers (0~9)

also, would wordlist generators make a significant time/performance difference?

Comment: To _generate_ the wordlist or to use it to crack some hash? Either way it would depend heavily on the software being used, and would take quite a bit of research to figure out without actually benchmarking the $1bn machine in person (or at least benchmarking its microprocessor).

Comment: How do you plan to store it? It would require something on the order of 2^305 bytes - or 10^75 or thereabout of the *biggest* drives around, for a total cost of 10^78 dollars or thereabout...

Comment: @forest I've seen several benchmarks for the Fugaku, but couldn't really understand how they could be used in practical life, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @MostafaNafady Those benchmarks tell you little to nothing about the computer's wordlist-generating or password-cracking performance.

Comment: @vidarlo I'll pipe the output :D I only want to measure how practical this supercomputer is in real scenarios.

Comment: @MostafaNafady Supercomputers are costly. They're *very* practical for whatever problem they're designed to solve. To generate ordered bytes you can probably do it far cheaper with a [ASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit). You don't need very many transistors to increment a counter by one...

Comment: @MostafaNafady I doubt "wordlist generation" was the scenario envisioned when this supercomputer's architecture was being designed.